# Android pull language xml file from SD Card, how?

Tags: android

Is here any way in android to use the strings.xml file from the SD_CARD? 
So basically I have a lot of string file on the SD, `strings_en.xml, strings_de.xml, strings_fr.xml` etc.

How can I load that file as a string xml file and refresh all views in my app in real time? (I have a lot of views so how can I load all strings in one, not one by one on my views)

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: u mean in runtime ?i think from network u can

Comment: I have this files on a server, I can download them as xml files to the sd_card and then how can I load them in real time, insteed of reopen my app?

Comment: did u tried any xml parsing lib ?

Comment: the real question is after the parse how can I Load all of my strings to my app? I have a lot of views and a lot of strings..

Comment: u need to restart ur app or activity .. hopefully i would like to show u demo ..willing to post soon

Comment: there are string_anyname in ur sdcard how would u know whick string to load ? will u send command to device in json format or how??

Comment: Hey have a look at my Answer..it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making a LanguageClass in which you do parsing and loading of strings in hashmap. In the same class create one more function to which you can pass "key" i.e. the string name and get the value.

```
public class LanguageLoader(){
    HashMap<String,String> strLangMap = new HashMap<String,String>;

    public void LoadLanguageData (String pathtolanguagepathxml){
         //do you xml parsing here and load values in the strLangMap
    }

    public String getString(String key){
        //get value of the corresponding key from strLangMap
    }
}
```

You need to call this LanguageLoader class one from application load and another from where user changes the application language.

And in each activity class set labels using this LanguageLoader class.

e.g. for your controls do all initialization in oncreate and do label setup in onResume.

```
LanguageLoader ll = new LanguageLoader();

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

tv.setText(ll.getString(tvlabel));
btn.setText(ll.getString(btnlabel));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bsically I idea is to parse String from SDcard --> Keep a file observer on assert so that if files change i get notification --> and refresh view

Below are Three Steps :

```
   1. Parse String.xml :

    class Product {

    public String name;

    }
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(
                    "temp.xml");
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in_s, null);

            parseXML(parser);

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        ArrayList<Product> products = null;
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Product currentProduct = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name = null;
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                products = new ArrayList();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();

                if (name.equals("string")) {
                    String xyz = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    System.out.println("1234567890***" + xyz);
                    currentProduct = new Product();
                    currentProduct.name = parser.nextText();
                    System.out.println("1234567890" + currentProduct.name);
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("resources")
                        && currentProduct != null) {
                    products.add(currentProduct);

                }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

        printProducts(products);
    }

    private void printProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) {
        String content = "";
        Iterator<Product> it = products.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Product currProduct = it.next();
            content = content + "nnnProduct :" + currProduct.name + "n";

        }

        TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        display.setText(content);
    }
```

}

```
2. Keep File Observer :
```

[FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html)

```
3.  Refresh Views :

private void restartActivity() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```